# Refresh a region in window before drawing text

Tags: c, windows, gdi

I'm drawing text on window at WM_PAINT message, is there any way i can refresh that window region before drawing a new line of text so the old text at the same location would get erased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002(VS.85).aspx) for the window with the `bErase` parameter set to `TRUE` so that it will erase itself before the WM_PAINT is generated.

This is often required when the window is a static text control, as those don't erase themselves automatically when you change their value.

Make sure your window is handling [WM_ERASEBKGND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648055(v=VS.85).aspx) properly and the window class doesn't have a NULL background brush, as this is the mechanism used by InvalidateRect to do the erasing.

Answer (score 0):

You could just [FillRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162719%28VS.85%29.aspx) over the old text first...

Comment: Yes, but it is not refreshing itself when i draw a rectangle over it.

Answer (score 0):

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL); //get windows handle whaterver if urs
HRGN hrgn;

 //get that specific region and repaint it by following line

hrgn = CreateRectRgn(10, 10, 100, 100);
SelectClipRgn(hDC, hrgn);
PaintDesktop(hDC);
```